# How to save etc/paths file after editing it

Tags: vi, homebrew

I'm trying to install Homebrew and I found out what I need to do in order to fix it but I don't know how to save the file. This is how I need to save my file in order for Homebrew to work. Thanks!

```
   $ sudo vi /etc/paths
    /usr/local/bin
    /usr/local/sbin
    /usr/bin
    /bin
    /usr/sbin
    /sbin
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After you finish editing the file:

1. Hit the <kbd>Esc</kbd>key
2. Hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and hit <kbd>Z</kbd> twice (i.e. `shift-Z-Z`)

For future reference, here's a [cheat sheet](http://www.lagmonster.org/docs/vi.html)

Comment: just opening /etc/paths with vim was enough for me

Answer (score 1):

You can also hit <kbd>esc</kbd> then <kbd>:wq</kbd> , that's a full colon to enter command mode followed by **w** to write the file then **q** to quit out of vi.

Comment: it says:
E45: 'readonly' option is set (add ! to override)

I can't save the file. Any suggestions?

Comment: Perms issue. here's an Q&A that might be useful https://askubuntu.com/questions/635779/e45-readonly-option-is-set-add-to-override